# Sometimes Facebook doesn't return the auth_nonce parameter during authentication

Tags: facebook, facebook-oauth, nonce

I am using the `auth_nonce` parameter during the server-side authentication flow. However, I'm getting a problem where sometimes Facebook doesn't return the `auth_nonce` argument in the final step, which of course causes the authentication to fail.

Often it works just fine. These cases are when the user is initially logging in to my application, and I request that Facebook reauthenticate them (`auth_type=reauthenticate`). I've never seen this fail.

When it does fail, it's always after the user has logged in, and their auth_token has expired, and I'm silently reauthenticating them between page loads to get a new auth_token.

In these latter cases, the URL redirection looks something like this:

1. `http://myapplication.url` (notices token is expired, so sends the user to...)
2. `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id={APP_ID}&redirect_uri=http%3a%2f%2fmyapplication%2eurl%2ffacebook%2fafterlogin&scope=list,of,permissions&display=page&auth_nonce=Vr6EgapnMFIKrbMtVrdcZDTbioGe715pWDtMveA8z4xVNMR5IzGYoPN3rSxf` (Facebook redirects them to...)
3. `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request?app_id={APP_ID}&display=page&next=http%3A%2F%2Fmyapplication.url%2Ffacebook%2Fafterlogin&response_type=code&auth_nonce=Vr6EgapnMFIKrbMtVrdcZDTbioGe715pWDtMveA8z4xVNMR5IzGYoPN3rSxf&fbconnect=1&perms=list%2Cof%2Cpermissions` (Finally, we get redirected back to...)
4. `http://myapplication.url/facebook/afterlogin?code={Big long code here}#_=_`

During that last call, I GET the following URL:

`https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={APP_ID}&redirect_uri={THE_PROPER_REDIRECT_URL}&client_secret={APP_SECRET}&code={Big long code here}`

The reply I get back is in the form:

`access_token={AUTH_TOKEN}&expires=5083`

According to the documentation (and my experience during normal authentication), there should be a `auth_nonce` parameter in the final reply which I can validate.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: This is happening to me as well. I haven't found any documentation about this problem online. The docs say that you should expect an `auth_nonce` paramater in the request, as you expect, but it doesn't seem to do so in practice.